# Feature request: multiple "ask question" drafts

Tags: feature-request, draft

Currently, if you ask a question, the draft gets saved on the account. So, you can start drafting a question and then do research or other stuff and when you come back, the draft is saved, and you can continue until posting it.

But I just thought, it would be nice if you can have multiple drafts since I started drafting something for work purposes a few days ago, and now I wanted to ask another question. Now I have to delete the draft to create a new question, and that's bad because I have to recreate the deleted draft for work on Monday.

Comment: Maybe you can post your drafted question and immediately delete it. You should have access to it, and will have a chance to edit and undelete it later. (But I'm not sure if it's against any rules)

Comment: No, do not do that, @markalex. Only post content that you are ready to publish here.